# Using MapStruct mapping unable to map a Object class to another Dto object

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

Using mapStruct unable to map a Object class to another Dto object
below is the interface

```java
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

import com.ombudsman.service.respondent.model.Case;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface EmployeeMapper{
    EmployeeMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( EmployeeMapper.class );     
  
    Employee employeeData(Object caseList);
```

In my another class where I map the data

```java
final EmployeeMapper employeeMapper = Mappers.getMapper(EmployeeMapper.class);              
Employee cs=employeeMapper.employeeData(caseListDetails.get(0));
```

Error message I get as follows

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class com.EmployeeMapperImpl does not define or 
inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract com.model.Employee employeeDataDto(java.lang.Object)'
 of interface com.EmployeeMapper.
    .....
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccess
```

What is the root cause of the issue.

Comment: The method signature of `Emplyee emplyeeData(Object caseList)` looks wrong; I would expect a type of 'EmplyoeeDTO` or similar. Do you have a [MRE], e.g. in form of a git repository, you can share? --- A remark: Since we use `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")`, we can inject the mapper instead of creating it programmatically.

Comment: Emplyee emplyeeData(Object caseList)  this is working with dozar mapper but not with mapStruct

Comment: could you tell me why Emplyee emplyeeData(Object caseList) -this is wrong?

Comment: Because mapstruct generates code based on the method signatures. It analyzes both the parameter type(s) and the return type and generates the mapper method during code generation.

Comment: I have Object which returns from database, I need to map to Employee DTO class. So, what should be correct method signature ?

Comment: Why do you receive an `Object` from the database? You should be receiving some entity, The post - in its current form - is missing information. Please [edit] the post and add a [MRE].

Comment: @Turing85 - Data returns from store procedure which returns 2 result sets. So unable to map to entity class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256578/discussion-between-rand-and-turing85).

Comment: you should use a bean of `EmployeeMapper`. use autowired instance or , get the bean from application context

Comment: @namila007 - could you please share a sample code as you have mentioned above?

Comment: @rand like this https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#using-dependency-injection